# Why each functor defines an invariant, but not every invariant is functorial ? Examples?

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic

> In Category Theory each functor defines an invariant, but not every invariant is functorial

**Why** ? 
Can you provide some examples when

- a functor is an invariant
- a invariant is a functorial
- a invariant ***is not*** functorial

I need also another example:
- a functor ***is not*** an invariant $=>$ this is [absurd](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/561/what-is-the-difference-between-reductio-ad-absurdum-and-proof-by-contradictio) and false but I need that you show me the underlying contradiction

*Idea*

> For $A$ a monoid equipped with an action on an object $V$, an **invariant** of the action is an generalized element of $V$ which is taken by the action to itself, hence a fixed point for all the operations in the monoid..
>
> An ***action*** of a category $C$ on a set $S$ is nothing but a **functor** $\rho : C \to$ Set.

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking. A functor is an invariant with respect to which action? One example of a non-functorial invariant might be the automorphism group, but is this what you mean? Maybe it could help if you can give a reference to your opening statement?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: A functor is an invariant in the sense that it preserves isomorphisms. At least that's my guess as to what the OP is talking about.

Comment: I suspect you are conflating two different usages of the word "invariant". Can you provide the reference(s) you got the two quote blocks from?

Comment: @DenisNardin is taken from [here](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invarianza_(matematica)) when they write (is in italian) *"In teoria delle categorie, ogni funtore definisce un invariante, ma non ogni invariante è funtoriale"*

Comment: The first quote block is easy to interpret : if $F$ is a functor, it preserves identities and composition, hence isomorphisms, and therefore is an invariant. However, for instance the cardinal is an invariant of a set which is not a functor on $\mathbf{Set}$ (although you can make it functorial by modifying the domain, but that's the case for any invariant : just take the discrete underlying category)

Comment: Well, with a narrow enough view there will be invariants which are not functorial. For instance, the [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) seem to qualify.

Comment: Classic example/exercise: taking the centre of a group is not functorial with respect to homomorphisms

Comment: @Oscar That page is just terrible. I am strongly tempted to rewrite it (alas the quality of the Italian Wikipedia has a big variance).

Comment: Quella pagina di wikipedia mi ha fatto dimenticare cosa significa "invariante"

Comment: @DenisNardin *module* of a complex number under complex conjugation is an invariant but is also functorial? Why?

Comment: @Oscar If you'll accept a suggestion from me, ignore everything written on that page. It is conflating different meanings of the word "invariant" in order to give as many examples as possible, which is... not a good thing to do. If you want we could discuss a bit in chat to understand what is the underlying question that is confusing you, right now this question should probably be closed as "unclear what you're asking"